Adding a dataframe to an existing delta table throws DELTA_FAILED_TO_MERGE_FIELDS error
Fix
Issue was due to mismatched data types. Explicitly declaring schema type resolved the issue.
schema = StructType([
   StructField("_id", StringType(), True),
   StructField("department_id", IntegerType(), True),
   StructField("first_name", StringType(), True),
   StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
   StructField("last_name", StringType(), True),
   StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True)])

Original Post
Resubmitting with some edits as old one was flagged for not being focused enough
New to Pyspark and parquet/delta ecosystem.
I'm trying to write a script (using Pyspark) that does the following

Save a parquet file in delta table format.
Create a delta table object on top of that file.
Add record to table.
Check table version after operation.

I am able to do till step 2 but steps 3 and 4 error out. Any idea -

How to get the delta table version number?
Why am I getting an error on appending a spark dataframe to an existing delta table?

Script
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from delta import *
from delta.tables import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

from pyspark import SparkFiles
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

print("Kernel:", sys.executable)
print("Python version:", sys.version)
print("Spark version:", spark.version)
print("PySpark version:", pyspark.__version__)
print("PySpark Version :", spark.sparkContext.version)
    
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0")
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .getOrCreate()
)

delta_table_path = "output/data_delta_table"

.......
.......
        
    # save to delta format file (overwrite if exists)
spark_dataframe_parq.write.mode(saveMode="overwrite").format("delta").save(delta_table_path)
        
    # read delta table
    deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_table_path)    
    
    # check table details 
    print ("Delta Table details: ", deltaTable.detail())
    
    # check version before
    print ("Delta Table Version Before : " , deltaTable.version()) # <<< Issue 1

   
    # Add new spark dataframe and append to delta table 
    schema = ("_id","department_id","first_name","id","last_name","salary")
    data = [("6407c350840f10d7f3e769f8",1500,"Justin",2002,"Simon",100300)]
    new_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

    new_df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(delta_table_path) # <<< Issue 2

Output
Python version: 3.9.6 (default, Mar 29 2024, 10:51:09)
[Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)]
Spark version: 3.5.1
PySpark version: 3.5.1
PySpark Version : 3.5.1
...
...
...
Delta Table details :  DataFrame[format: string, id: string, name: string, description: string, location: string, createdAt: timestamp, lastModified: timestamp, partitionColumns: array<string>, clusteringColumns: array<string>, numFiles: bigint, sizeInBytes: bigint, properties: map<string,string>, minReaderVersion: int, minWriterVersion: int, tableFeatures: array<string>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/foobar/workspace/practice/deltalake/parquet_delta_example_using_spark.py", line 151, in <module>
print ("Delta Table Version Before : " , deltaTable.version())
AttributeError: 'DeltaTable' object has no attribute 'version'
...
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/foobar/workspace/practice/deltalake/parquet_delta_example_using_spark.py", line 157, in <module>
new_df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(delta_table_path)
File "/Users/foobar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1463, in save
self._jwrite.save(path)
File "/Users/foobar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
return_value = get_return_value(
File "/Users/foobar/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
raise converted from None
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [DELTA_FAILED_TO_MERGE_FIELDS] Failed to merge fields 'department_id' and 'department_id'


seems like type incompatibility: https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/failed-to-merge-fields-error-on-delta-live-tables/td-p/45068 have you tried checking department_id in original (saved) delta table?

@GeorginaSkibinski- Thank you for pointing that out.  Declaring schema type resolved the issue .   I will post the fix in the original question above.   Any idea about the versioning ?

@GeorginaSkibinski- do you want to repost your comment as an solution so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

It seems your schema is incompatible, try maybe to validate if department_id type in original (saved) delta table aligns with the type from the dataframe you want to append.
See similar issue here.

Thank you for pointing that out. Declaring schema type resolved the issue . I will post the fix in the original question above.
